# Get value of multiple keys for sorted set using stackexchange.redis

Tags: azure, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I'm using stackexchange.redis for my azure redis processes. Im storing my data as (sorted set) zset. Its key - (value - score).

What i need is to query multiple keys at the same time in a request.  Im using "SortedSetRangeByRankWithScores" but it only allows one key for a request.

If its not possible, i need to change all my data structure to simple string as value(json). Then i may be able to query multiple keys.

Any suggested way of doing that?